# Rails error with my database when I try to access to index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a database named WhiteHouse where it has about 450 White house staff and I have my home directory (root) pointed to the index of the database.

Below is the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'WhiteHouse.employees' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `employees` (Ruby on Rails)
app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

I checked out the naming conventions of rails and my files in the MVC architecture were named appropriately. However, when I open the local server and try to open up the home page, it gives me that error in the index method of my controller class. My employees_controller.rb file is below:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  def index
     @employees = Employee.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @employees }
  end
end
```

Can someone please assist me?

I already migrated it successfully because the schema.rb file updated along with the migration.

```
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters   
    /abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `query'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapte/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `block in execute'

activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'

activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `execute'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:257:in `execute_and_free'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:424:in `columns'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:237:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:129:in `locking_enabled?'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/relation.rb:170:in `exec_queries'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:105:in `find'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:5:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__351996495__process_action__315798478__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__787982263__call__784807942__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
```

Comment: Are you sure that the tables that you need are created? Are you using migrations? Is it an error related with `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Please post the *entire* stack trace so we can see what the actual error is in addition to its location.

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Table 'WhiteHouse.employees' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `employees`

Rails.root: /usr/rails_projects/dummy_app

Comment: Definitely looks like you haven't run the migrations yet.

Comment: To see if the table is in the correct database, you can try:  
  
    $ rails dbconsole  
    mysql> desc employees;  
  
If the table exists in the right place it should show you the columns for employees.  (Apologies but I can't get the formatting I want here.)

Comment: @mharper i did what you said and I got this as the response: Usage: dbconsole [environment] [options]
    -p, --include-password           Automatically provide the password from database.yml
        --mode [MODE]                Automatically put the sqlite3 database in the specified mode (html, list, line, column).
        --header

Comment: It's actually two separate commands:  "rails dbconsole" followed by "desc employees;"  Sorry for the confusion.